# passing an object with for loop. Android

Tags: java, android

I want to pass values to the add-temple class using for loop.

**My add temple function:**

```
 // Adding new temple
 public void Add_Temple(kovil Kovil) {
 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

values.put(KEY_TMPNAME, Kovil.gettemplename()); 
values.put(KEY_TMPTYPE, Kovil.gettempletype()); 
values.put(KEY_LATITUDE, Kovil.getlatitude()); 
values.put(KEY_LONGITUDE, Kovil.getlongitude()); 
values.put(KEY_IMGNAME, Kovil.getimage_name()); 
values.put(KEY_YEARBUILD, Kovil.getyear_build()); 
values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, Kovil.getaddress()); 
values.put(KEY_CITY, Kovil.getcity()); 
values.put(KEY_EMAIL, Kovil.getemail()); 
values.put(KEY_WEB, Kovil.getwebsite()); 
values.put(KEY_TEL1, Kovil.gettelephone1()); 
values.put(KEY_TEL2, Kovil.gettelephone2());
values.put(KEY_DESCRI, Kovil.getDescription());

// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_TEMPLE, null, values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

My for loop to send values to the Add temple function:

```
        kovil insertData1 = new kovil("temple_name", "temple_type", "latitude",  "longitude", "image_name", "year_build", "address", "city", "email", "website", "telephone1", "telephone2",  "Description");
       // dbhand .Add_Temple(insertData1 );

        kovil insertData2 = new kovil("temple_name2", "temple_type2", "latitude2",  "longitude2", "image_name2", "year_build2", "address2", "city2", "email2", "website2", "telephone12", "telephone22",  "Description2");
      //  dbhand .Add_Temple(insertData2 );

        for(int i=0;i<2; i++){

            dbhand .Add_Temple("insertData"+i);

        }
```

I get a syntax error in the for loop. Can some one help me to write this for loop please.

**error message**

```
Multiple markers at this line
- insertData cannot be resolved to a variable
- The method Add_Temple(kovil) in the type Dbhandler is not applicable for the arguments 
 (String)
```

Comment: Do you not think that adding the error message would help people to help you?

Comment: please post the error message

Comment: the error message is that dbhand .Add_Temple() accepts arguments of type kovil not of type string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Add_Temple function argument is of type "kovil", you are passing String type instead.

You should put your "kovil" objects to ArrayList, for example, and then iterate through it like so:

```
ArrayList<kovil> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(insertData1);
arrayList.add(insertData2);
for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
    dbhand.Add_Temple(arrayList.get(i));
};
```

Comment: yes, i can simply pass it one by one `dbhand .Add_Temple(insertData1);` like this. but i want to do it in a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing something like this

```
Kovil insertData1 = new Kovil("temple_name", "temple_type", "latitude",  "longitude", "image_name", "year_build", "address", "city", "email", "website", "telephone1", "telephone2",  "Description");


Kovil insertData2 = new Kovil("temple_name2", "temple_type2", "latitude2",  "longitude2", "image_name2", "year_build2", "address2", "city2", "email2", "website2", "telephone12", "telephone22",  "Description2");

Kovil[] array = new Kovil[]{insertData1, insertData2};

for(Kovil k : array) {
   dbhand .addTemple(k);
}
```

***On a side note:***

Please fix the keyword,function naming, follow Java naming conventions